# node.js ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

Tags: node.js, firebase

Currently "trying" to get firebase to work on next.js but is not working, Ive tried multiply way but what ever I do, it always keeps getting caught on

`(!firebase.apps.length)`

if its not `!` it is `ReferenceError: firebase is not defined` and adding `import firebase from "firebase"` isn't working either

code below

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { firestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {

apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
authDomain: process.env.BOOSTING_BAZAAR_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
projectId: process.env.BOOSTING_BAZAAR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
storageBucket: process.env.BOOSTING_BAZAAR_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
messagingSenderId: process.env.BOOSTING_BAZAAR_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
appId: process.env.BOOSTING_BAZAAR_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
measurementId: process.env.BOOSTING_BAZAAR_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}
```

Im currently at wits end

Answer (score 0):

To provide the service account json to firebase. You have to import `firebase-admin` in `node.js`.

You can initialize firebase with this code :

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

try{
    admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}catch(e){

}
```

For NextJS they have provided proper method :

1. Install with npm :

   ```
   npm install firebase
   ```
2. Import library and initialize app.

   ```
   import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
   const firebaseConfig = {
   };

   const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `getApps()` function in the new Modular SDK (which does not use the `firebase.` namespace):

```js
import { initializeApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";

if (!getApps().length) {
  initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}
```

Although you don't need to check if there's a Firebase instance already initialized with that config in the new SDK. It does not throw "firebase app exists" errors.

Answer (score -1):

Check your code with the snippet below. It should solve the problem. This is how I set my own app. Also make sure firebase is installed in your application.

You can try re-installing with the package manager you use. I.e either `npm` or `yarn`. The firebase variable will also not be available because of your import pattern.

```js
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/analytics';

//  TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.BOOSTING_BAZAAR_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.BOOSTING_BAZAAR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.BOOSTING_BAZAAR_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.BOOSTING_BAZAAR_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.BOOSTING_BAZAAR_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.BOOSTING_BAZAAR_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

const storage = firebase.storage();

export { storage, firebase as default };
```